# Xamarin Tabbed Page tabs aren't filling the space?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TabbedPage in my Xamarin.Forms app that refuses to fill the available space when deployed to an Android tablet. Testing on a Pixel emulator renders the navigation tabs properly - they have an icon, a title, and they fill the available screen space; whereas on a tablet in landscape mode, they stay as tiny square-shaped tabs.

I'm generating the tabs in C# as I need the pages with particular constructors. I can't find any HorizontalOptions properties either here in C# or in the .xaml of the TabbedPage that I would normally think to set to FillAndExpand. How do I do this?

```
//TabbedPage (HomePage) generation code in C#
//There is no additional styling in the .xaml file.

public HomePage(Type1 type1, Type2 type2)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.type1 = type1;
            this.type2 = type2;
            var page1 = new FirstPage(type1, type2);
            page1.IconImageSource = "ic_one.png";
            page1.Title = "Page 1";
            var page2 = new SecondPage(type1, type2);
            page2.IconImageSource = "ic_two.png";
            page2.Title = "Page 2";
            var page3 = new ThirdPage(type1, type2);
            page3.IconImageSource = "ic_three.png";
            page3.Title = "Page 3";

            Children.Add(page1);
            Children.Add(page2);
            Children.Add(page3);
        }

 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package **Naxam.BottomTabbedPage** from nuget.

Change the root element to BottomTabbedPage (change the code behind as well)

```
<naxam:BottomTabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
    xmlns:naxam="clr-namespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.Controls.Forms"
    x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
    <local:Page1 />
    <local:Page2 />
    <local:Page3 />
    <local:Page4 />
    <local:Page5 />
</naxam:BottomTabbedPage>
```

Change the colors/heights in your activity class

```
BottomTabbedRenderer.BackgroundColor = new Android.Graphics.Color(23, 31, 50);
BottomTabbedRenderer.FontSize = 10;
BottomTabbedRenderer.IconSize = 20;
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemTextColor = stateList;
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemIconTintList = stateList;
BottomTabbedRenderer.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(this.Assets, "HiraginoKakugoProNW3.otf");
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemBackgroundResource = Resource.Drawable.bnv_selector;
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemSpacing = 8;
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemPadding = new Xamarin.Forms.Thickness(8);
BottomTabbedRenderer.BottomBarHeight = 80;
BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemAlign = BottomTabbedRenderer.ItemAlignFlags.Center;
```

For more details you can check [here](https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms) .

Comment: Appreciate the response, it looks very useful. Do the tabs have to be at the bottom of the page? I'd prefer to keep them in the bar at the top if I could.

Comment: I'm afraid that you could not let the tabbar on the top of page if you use this plugin. Otherwise you need to customize it by yourself,which maybe a little complex .